# Mac apache server issue

Tags: macos, apache, localhost

Something really weird is going on. For some reason i see my localhost when i type in "sweet.com" in my browser.
It is not something i have setup (not on purpose).

I have check my http.conf and search for "sweet", but nothing.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

I know very little on the server topic so i'm properly looking in the wrong place.

Can this just happen and how do i turn it off?

I have installed different thing with composer, can it come from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `dig sweet.com` you will see that `sweet.com` simply resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Okay thanks. But what does that mean? That everyone that type in sweet.com and has a local server will see there localhost or?

Comment: Yes. (Apparently, that was too short for a comment, so I have to type a bit more here. Sometimes, things really *are* that simple. :-) )